# Castlabs electron app breaks when running on certain MacOS versions

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I have developed a DRM playback app using the Castlabs electron fork for Content Security (https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases) on MacOS High Sierra. I am receiving reports of the application failing to start on some MacOS versions with the following error message:

```
Process:               indee [52975]
Path:                  /Applications/indee.app/Contents/MacOS/indee
Identifier:            com.electron.indee
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           indee [52975]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2019-02-25 20:25:09.463 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4BF915F3-40DA-0ABC-3930-F21B00CF3FD7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       69FABBB3-0032-4519-81B0-0CB25B679ACC

Time Awake Since Boot: 650000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       240 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom
Referenced from: /Applications/indee.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
in /Applications/indee.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
```

From what I can tell, this issue is not consistently reproducible across different Macs running the same macOS version but it is common enough that it is creating problems. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, a couple of issues reported in [electron-releases](https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases/) discusses the cause and solution for this problem: [#34](https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases/issues/34) and [#30](https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases/issues/30).

In short, this problem occurs when a build is using an older version of the MacOSX10.12 SDK where the availability macros are incorrectly indicating availability of the `kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom` symbol on target os versions where it is not. This causes non-weak linking to be used for the symbol, effectively making it required, and thus causes failure on systems where it is missing (i.e. systems prior to 10.12 - Sierra). The solution for us was to use a corrected version of the MacOSX10.12 SDK, such as the one provided with `Xcode 8.3.3`, when building our releases.